# Should I run tests with Ruby 1.9.2 if they pass in 1.8.7 and 1.9.3?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec

I have a [Ruby gem that is setup with Travis CI](http://travis-ci.org/#!/beerlington/classy_enum), and [my configuration](https://github.com/beerlington/classy_enum/blob/master/.travis.yml) currently runs the specs with Ruby 1.8.7, 1.9.2, and 1.9.3, as well as the latest versions of Rails 3.0, 3.1, and 3.2. If the tests are passing in 1.8.7 and 1.9.3, is there any reason to run them in 1.9.2? It seems like overkill if anything that works in both 1.8.7 and 1.9.3 will always work in 1.9.2. Is that assumption correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see a reason, why it shouldn't work with 1.9.2 -- but that's the thing with testing: you never know. So if it is important to you that your software works with 1.9.2, I would not run the tests automatically and during development, but at least before an important deployment.